# How to manage availability of a user in MySQL database tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am trying to make a database design and I have a tutor which can set his availability in two ways :

1. General availability in a week. Which basically tells that usually I'm free to teach on these days of week between these hours of those days. E.g. I'm available on Monday from 4PM to 8PM, on Tuesday on 10AM to 1PM, etc.
2. Specific availability. Which tells that on this date I won't be available on general availability time but instead on these hours. E.g. I'm available on Monday 28 June from 2PM to 5PM.
   If specific availability for a date is present then general availability won't be shown.

How do I design tables in order to save this availability information ?

Comment: You can have two tables or a single table. This is not a big issue unless those two row types start  behave differently in some relationships.

Comment: @Serg I don't think using single table would be a good idea general availability doesn't need date but specific availability does so I need two tables but the problem is I don't know how to store the availability timing. For general availability should I create a table with all the days i.e. from Monday to Sunday as columns ? But then what will I store in the rows I can't store a range like 4PM to 6PM that would make my columns multi valued thus not atomic. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example provided your DB supports `Time` type, pseudocode

```
GeneralAvailability (
    TutorId int not null,
    DayOfWeek int not null, /* 1 .. 7*/
    TimeFrom Time not null,
    TimeTo Time  not null
) 

SpecialAvailability (
    TutorId  int not null,
    AvailDate Date not null, 
    TimeFrom Time not null,
    TimeTo Time  not null
)
```

or generalized one

```
Availability (
    TutorId int  not null,
    DayOfWeek int, /* 1 .. 7, null */ 
    AvailDate Date, 
    TimeFrom Time  not null,
    TimeTo Time  not null,
    CHECK ((DayOfWeek IS NULL OR AvailDate IS NULL) AND (DayOfWeek IS NOT NULL OR AvailDate IS NOT NULL))
)
```